# Clean git deployment workflow

Tags: git, version-control, workflow, git-flow

We are trying to implement an automated workflow for deployment based on git. Currently, we have three environments: development/staging/production. The idea was to mark those environments as branches of the same name (except production=Master), we then have developed a small CLI which takes commands like this:

```
cli deploy -e production -t patch
```

This runs a bunch of internal tasks and, as a final step, merges the local branch into the correct environment branch (in this case Master), then bumps the version in `package.json` according to SemVer specification (in this case, a patch level version will increment the major.minor.**patch** part) and tags the commit appropriately.

This works very well: we always know what is deployed in which environment, we can rollback easily and we have taken certain steps out of individual developers mistakes.

However, this also results in a less than pretty git log. First off, branch Master is comprised only of merge commits (`Merge branch 'hotfix'`, `Merge branch release-2.0.0`, etc.), since we decided to keep the branch history intact. Is this the way it is supposed to look like in the [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) Model?

Also, we bump the version after the merge, so really Master branch looks always like: `Merge branch 'hotfix'`, `Bumping version to 2.3.1`.

This looks quite ugly and, especially as the project grows, starts becoming more confusing. I'm sure there must be a cleaner way to do this, but I can't figure out what we could adjust.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use the master branch name and can rename it  to production, see something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762601/how-do-i-rename-my-git-master-branch-to-release

Comment: Ah well, that's not really the problem. I don't mind the branch being named Master.