# How do I change the branch to commit (master > main) using git bash?

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-branch

I'll summarize what happened to my computer.

### What I wanted to do

To upload my local folder "freshman" to github repository named "Hanyang", I typed the commands below;

```
git init
git add freshman
git commit -m "blahblah"
git remote add origin https://github.com/myUsername/Hanyang.git
git push -u origin master
git push origin master
```

### What happened

But I realized that the folder is well uploaded but inadvertently at the '**master**' branch, while the default branch was '**main**'.
So I manually deleted '**master**' branch in github, got back to git bash then tried `git add freshman` again.

> Did I have to do something to change the target branch (**master** > **main**) before merely trying `git add freshman` again?

Anyway unlike the first typing of the command, however, git bash says "nothing is added" even I checked it via `git status` - besides it says "my branch is up to date with 'origin/master' " which I already deleted as [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlOD2.png).

### What I want to do now

In this situation, what should I do to upload my ''freshman'' folder to the **main** branch of the repository in github such that I can upload other folders (sophomore, etc.) after this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I rename my Git 'master' branch to 'release'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762601/how-do-i-rename-my-git-master-branch-to-release)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - run `git branch` to see what branch you are on
> - to switch to main if not on main run `git checkout main`
> - if branch `main` doesn't exist locally you will need to run `git branch main` before checking it out
> - Then you can add your file, set the remote for the `main` branch, and push to `origin main`

Comment: When I run ```git branch```, the result is main in green color and another trash one that I created minutes ago by mistake. Does this mean that I'm already on main?

Comment: @AhnJun-Yeong yeah that means you're on main, so all you'll have to do is push to `origin main`

Comment: but still ```git commit``` doesn't work with the message "Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master' and 'nothing added to commit". Of course I tried directly ```git push origin main``` but only to be rejected.

Comment: @AhnJun-Yeong idk if this is a great solution, but it should work, I'd SAVE FRESHMEN SOMEWHERE then run `git reset --hard origin main`, add freshmen back if removed, run git add freshmen, git commit, git push

Comment: okay that must be detour but i think it must work as well!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch -M main
```

For more information, look under [Branching & Merging](https://github.com/joshnh/Git-Commands).